# Azure Data Factory: How to add timezone offset value to a timestamp field

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a timestamp field with sample value : `2021-05-28 11:05:18`
also another field called offset value which has values `(-400).`

How can I add this offset value and get the timestamp value as : `2021-05-28 07:05:18`

I have tried timestamp_field + offset field but doesnt seem like working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [addHours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#addhours) function in Azure Data Factory.

```
addHours(2021-05-28 11:05:18, -4)
```

For version 1:

```
AddHours(2021-05-28 11:05:18, -4)
```